# Ошибка при первой установке свойства TextAlign контролу в Windows Forms Designer

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пишу собственную версию конструктора форм Windows Forms, и при первой попытке изменить значение свойства TextAlign я получаю следующую ошибку. При повторных - все работает.

Я проверил, что дизайнер тут вообще не при чем. Даже если на форму добавить PropertyGrid с кнопкой и попытаться изменить TextAlign, при первой попытке вижу ошибку. Проблему легко воспроизвести:

```
var form = new Form();
var pg = new PropertyGrid();
form.Controls.Add(pg);
pg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
pg.SelectedObject = new Button();
form.ShowDialog();
```

[image: Ошибка при первой попытке изменить TextAlign]

Comment: это просто скрин с непонятно чем, как с этим работать? Я так понимаю, саму ошибку вы уже гуглили и ничего не нашли, а код не показали, то есть работать не с чем.

Comment: А для чего тут код? Я проверял множество проектов по конструктору из CodeProject, в каждом из них есть эта ошибка. Даже в SharpDevelop она есть. Я использую DesignSurface.

Comment: ну, допустим, я бы хотел вам помочь, я читаю вопрос, но я без понятия, что именно вы делаете и откуда эта проблема возникает. И поскольку кода в вопросе нет, то я и воспроизвести не могу вашу проблему. То есть помогать тут не с чем, что я и написал.

Comment: Да, я тоже без понятия, откуда эта проблема возникает, иначе бы и не написал. Для проверки ошибки достаточно добавить Button или Label в SharpDevelop и попытаться отобразить окно редактирования свойства TextAlign. Я уверен, что наличие кода никак не поможет проблеме. Создаю экземпляр DesignSurface, помещаю в него собственные реализации служб, извлекаю View, помещаю его в видимый контейнер.

Comment: Я с вами спорить не буду, я вам просто подсказал как улучшить вопрос. Без четких шагов воспроизведения в вопросе, вам очень повезет, если кто то заморочится читать комментарии или гуглить вашу ошибку.

Comment: Гуглинг ошибки абсолютно бесполезен, вы не работаете с Windows Forms Designer?

Comment: У меня есть некоторый опыт, но это не важно по сути. Ваша задача тут - это описать ваш вопрос так, чтобы читатель этого вопроса захотел вам помочь. То есть захотел бы потратить своё время здесь для вас, бесплатно, просто чтобы помочь вам решить вашу проблему. Я вам говорю, что сейчас ваш вопрос не особо привлекателен, чтобы кто-то вам помог. Кто-то может и откликнется. но это маловероятно.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос, дизайнер вообще не при чем.

Comment: Что-то я не понял, ошибка возникает в вашем приложении или студии/другой IDE? Как это можно воспроизвести? Дизайнер форм студии не люблю, но работаю с ним и подобных проблем не замечал начиная с VS 2008. В других IDE тоже проблем не наблюдал. ОС какую используете, желательно с версией?

Comment: Ошибка возникает в ЛЮБОМ приложении, содержащим PropertyGrid, имеющем в SelectedObject кнопку/текст на ЛЮБОЙ версии Windows. Скорее всего, у вас тоже она будет.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/mutLltAksFmtzg

Comment: [Что я делаю не так?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKOIL.png) А если серьезно,  что-то поломалось в системе, если ошибка возникает независимо от приложения. Попробуйте воспроизвести вашу проблему на другом доступном вам компьютере. Во всяком случае ни C# вообще, ни WinForms в частности, тут ни при чем. И вы так и не ответили какую версию операционной системы используете.

Comment: Вы делаете то не так, что пытаетесь повторить баг на хорошо отлаженной версии в VS. Сделайте это же в скомпилированной программе.

Comment: @Antinet я же задавал вопрос "ошибка возникает в вашем приложении или студии/другой IDE?" на что вы ответили "Ошибка возникает в ЛЮБОМ приложении, содержащим PropertyGrid". Где это противоречит тому, что я использую студию для проверки вашей проблемы? Допишите в вопрос необходимые уточнения и минимальный код, который поможет воспроизвести вашу проблему, тут не принято вести длинные дискуссии в комментариях.

Comment: Между прочим, вы бы тоже могли уточнить, о какой "студии" идет речь. Из других IDE я работал в SharpDevelop, там тоже это не исправили. В вопрос добавлен минимальный код для воспроизведения бага.

Comment: Имею VS2010. До недавних пор (примерно месяца 3 назад) всё было замечательно. Пару недель назад писал WinForm проект столкнулся с подобными сообщениями при форматировании. Компьютер не получал официальные обновления и ничего не ставилось. Предположу, что это заложенное в .NET Framework уведомление. Попробуйте откатить системную дату и проверить её появление. Ах да. Использую .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Ошибка неоднократно проверялась на нескольких компьютерах с разными версиями Windows, и судя по ошибке, надо внести изменения в конфигурацию приложения. Однако как это сделать - никакой информации не нахожу. .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Воспроизвел, добавьте в вопрос версию .NET для которой должна быть сборка, потому что при сборке под текущую версию проблема не воспроизводится. Более того, если текущая версия 4.5.2, тоже не воспроизведется, там что-то поломали в 4.7.1 кажется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое может быть если приложение собрано под .NET Framevork 4.7 или ниже, а запускается в runtime версии 4.7.1 и выше.

В App.config добавьте или отредактируйте секцию runtime, чтобы получить примерно такой вид ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <!-- Это именно то, о чем говорит текст ошибки -->
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Я это значение уже именно так редактировал, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Antinet Если бы у меня ни чего не изменилось, не стал бы писать. Ошибка воспроизводится и убирается. Код использовал из вашего вопроса один в один. Возможно нужен принудительный rebuild, возможно с предварительной очисткой решения, но мне это не понадобилось.

Comment: 4.5.2 версия .NET?

Comment: @Antinet именно 4.5.2 с установленным 4.7.3. Можете попробовать такое значение "Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.3=false", по идее при нем должно отключиться вообще все. Оно есть в документации.

Comment: @Antinet а на 4.7.3 и не воспроизведется, там конфликта нет, все свое, совместимость не требуется. До 4.7 включительно такая же ошибка, при использовании Runtime 4.7.1 и выше.

Comment: Действительно, я попробовал создать новый проект и решил проблему.

Comment: Однако нет, проблема куда сложнее.

Comment: Ну тогда дописывайте детали, будем посмотреть.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что я забыл докладывать файл конфигурации при копировании. Вопрос не по теме, но его "таскание" с программой никак не входит в мои планы, как и его склеивание с ней. Не знаете, как эти настройки добавить в само приложение?

Comment: @Antinet давайте отдельным вопросом лучше, может еще кто подтянется. Сам такое не делал, не было необходимости. Если решение вас устраивает, не забывайте галочку под рейтингом ставить, чтобы другие пользователи знали, что решение есть и оно как минимум автору подошло. Ну а автору решения приятно =)

Comment: Галочку поставил, пишу новый вопрос.

Comment: А что это за .NET Framework 4.7.3? Я знаю только 4.7.2 и 4.8.

Comment: @Antinet очепятка, сорри, с версией языка перепуталось. а править комментарии можно только в течение 5 минут после публикации. 4.7.2 конечно, следующий 4.8 но его я пока не пробовал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99080/discussion-between-antinet-and-rdorn).